# C# Executing external process with spaces in path on Windows 8

Tags: c#

I have a problem starting a process in C# when there's a space in the path on Windows 8, *even when the path is in double quotes!*

The following code has been working fine for years on our XP and Windows 7 machines, but we recently switched some development boxes over to Windows 8 and we now get the following error:

`'D:\Workspace\Visual' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Code:

```
string command = "\"D:\\Workspace\\Visual Studio 2010\\Dev\\Tools\\Editors\\AssetManager\\bin\\Tools\\TextureAtlasBuilder.exe\"";
string arguments = "\"D:\\Local\\Temp\\xu2twc4d.cg1\" \"environment-textures\"";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    FileName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"{0}\cmd.exe", Environment.SystemDirectory),
    Arguments = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "/C {0} {1}", command, arguments)
};

Process process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = startInfo
};

process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(StandardOutputHandler);
process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(StandardErrorHandler);

process.Start();
```

I've tried literal strings with and without double quotes, verbatim strings with and without double quotes, and I always get the same error!

What am I doing wrong?!

Thanks

Comment: do you really have to start cmd first?

Comment: can you try to remove the " from your arguments string

Comment: I agree that in the code example, I probably don't need to start cmd, but this is generic code used to start different tools which aren't necessarily exe files (such as java or script programs). I've tested with a java program and I get the same error :-(

Comment: Since I can't yet answer my own question I'll do it here for now: As rene suggested, I've removed the double quotes from the argument list and it works as it should. As for why I only get the error on Windows 8, I have no idea... but at least it works now! Thanks!

Comment: I added my comments as answer and added my reasoning why I sugested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the " from your arguments string.

It is tricky because the cmd behavior with /C is very strict on the use of " as can be found out out from cmd /?. If all fails: write your commandline and arguments to a temporary cmd file and start that one...

> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
>   the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic
>   is used to process quote (") characters:
>
> ```
> 1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>     on the command line are preserved:
>
>     - no /S switch
>     - exactly two quote characters
>     - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>       where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>     - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>       two quote characters
>     - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>       of an executable file.
>
> 2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>     a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>     remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>     any text after the last quote character.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I am using following path, and it is successfully accepting.

```
string command1 = @"C:\test\ab ab\1.txt";
Process.Start(command1);
```